# PHP OOP MySQL Registration System MySQL_NUM_Row error

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Well, my registration works apart from the fact that the code to detect whether a user has already been created does not.

```
public function register($username, $password) { 
  global $core, $db; 

  $username = $core->encrypt($username); 
  $password = $core->encrypt($password); 

  $qry = $db->query("SELECT * 
                       FROM `users` 
                      WHERE `username` = '$username' 
                        AND `password` = '$password'"); 
  $num = $db->num($qry); 

  if($num >= 1) { 
    echo 'This username has already been registered'; 
  } else { 
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `users` 
                  (username, password) 
                VALUES 
                  ('{$username}', '{$password}');"); 
  } 
}
```

This is the code that I have used, I think it's some form of error to do with the query but I'm not sure what - probably a minor mistake.

MySQL Error:

```
>Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\housekeeping\_inc\db.inc.php on line 14

>$db->num code
        public function num($query) {
            mysql_num_rows($query); << line 14
        }
```

Comment: are you sure that $db->query returns the result (instead of true/false perhaps).

Comment: just inside the function, after the globals, try: "print_r($db);" and see what you get

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the **return** statement in your num function and your qry function. It should be:

```
public function num($query) {
    return mysql_num_rows($query);
}
```

You didn't provide the code for your qry function but it should be something like this:

```
public function qry($sql) {
    return mysql_query($sql);
}
```